# Component not working in IE 11 even with Polyfill

Tags: vue.js, quill

I'm new to VueJS and I'm trying to just get a piece of code I found on the web working using Quill wrapped in Vue.

It works PERFECTLY in Chrome but I need it to work in IE 11. I've tried polyfills but its not working.

I need this using a CDN and not CLI as it's for an Outlook Add-In.

The code I'm working with is on my codepen:

`https://codepen.io/ziggythecompace/pen/BaNRERR`

The HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Trying to use the Quill Editor in Vue</title>
    <!-- https://pineco.de/wrapping-quill-editor-in-a-vue-component/ -->
    <!-- This works! -->

    <!-- Include stylesheet -->
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.core.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.4/quill.bubble.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">
        <editor v-model="model"></editor>
        <p>I need the v-html directive: <span v-html="model"></span></p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="quill_in_wrapper.js"></script>
            

</body>
</html>
```

The JavaScript:

```js
Vue.component('editor', {
    /*template: `
        <div ref="editor"></div>
    `,*/

    template: '<div ref="editor"></div>',

    props: {
        value: {
            type: String,
            default: ''
        }
    },

    data() {
        return {
            editor: null
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.editor = new Quill(this.$refs.editor, {
            modules: {
                toolbar: [
                    [{ header: [1, 2, 3, 4, false] }],
                    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
                ]
            },
            //theme: 'bubble',
            theme: 'snow',
            formats: ['bold', 'underline', 'header', 'italic'],
            placeholder: "Type something in here!"
        });

        this.editor.root.innerHTML = this.value;

        this.editor.on('text-change', () => this.update());
    },

    methods: {
        update() {
            this.$emit('input', this.editor.getText() ? this.editor.root.innerHTML : '');
        }
    }
})

new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    data: {
        //model: 'Testing an editor'
        model: ''
    }

})
```

The polyfill isn't there. Any suggestions I'd be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: I'm almost sure that IE11 is not supported anymore since they removed it out of their readme: https://github.com/quilljs/quill

Answer (score 1):

Quill editor is not compatible with any IE version:

[image]

> https://github.com/quilljs/quill

You could try to run the quill code through *Babel* and see if that grants you a compatible version, but I wouldn't recommend being too hopeful about it.

Comment: What do you recommend I use for a Rich Text Editor with Vue and IE 11?

Comment: We don't recommend software or tools on StackOverflow.

Comment: OK. I got this working in Edge and Chrome. What I'm actually doing is trying to get Quill into an Office 365 add-in under Outlook. Quill does work in there on its own. But, it seems Outlook doesn't like components.

Can anyone direct me how to perhaps just use the Quill in a Vue instance and out of the component?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the code and just put everything into es5 and it worked.